# Mutliple Selection Drop down applied to multiple sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have the below code that works a treat on one sheet for selecting multiple options into one cell from a dropdown list, but I am borrowing code and I am not a code monkey so is there a way to do this function and apply it to multiple sheets?

Its the same column across the multiple sheets

```js
function onEdit(e) {
    var oldValue;
    var newValue;
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var activeCell = ss.getActiveCell();
    if (activeCell.getColumn() == 3 && activeCell.getRow() == 1 && ss.getActiveSheet().getName() == "Sheet1") {
        newValue = e.value;
        oldValue = e.oldValue;
        if (!e.value) {
            activeCell.setValue("");
        } else {
            if (!e.oldValue) {
                activeCell.setValue(newValue);
            } else {
                if (oldValue.indexOf(newValue) < 0) {
                    activeCell.setValue(oldValue + ',' + newValue);
                } else {
                    activeCell.setValue(oldValue);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove  `&& ss.getActiveSheet().getName() == "Sheet1"`. It's a condition that makes the code work only in the sheet names `Sheet1`.

Comment: @Manimator If this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.